# Open dialog which I can input path in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to open a dialog in VB.NET(2013) which can input a file path
I used `OpenFileDialog` method but it can't input file path .

[image]

Is there any way to input a file path?

I want to show dialog can select a txt or tsv file or can input the path what I want to select.
However OpenFileDialog method only can select a file.
inputting the path isn't possible .

the purpose is show the window to user, and user can select a file( directly select or input a path)

```
OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() 
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 
　　If BatchMain(False, OpenFileDialog1.FileName, Me.CmbPROC_CLS.SelectedCode) Then 
　　End If 
END If
```

Comment: What do you actually mean? Are you talking about the user not being able to enter a file path or you not being able to do so in the code you haven't shown us? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which always includes any relevant code. Also, always keep [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in mind.

Comment: I suspect you want the FolderBrowserDialog, not OpenFileDialog.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @Craig, I hope you're wrong, given that the OP specified "file path" three times in the question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - tryin' to take a guess on a question that's not worded great.  You can enter the full path + filename using "OpenFileDialog", so my assumption is that the OP wants to just enter a path (to their files), then they'll potentially iterate the files that are in that path ...... as I say, half a guess

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on which dialogue you should be using as well.  Do you want the user to select a known file name from a folder, or do you want the user to be able to select any file?  If you do in fact want a file dialog, thing the FileDialog.InitialDirectory property is probably want you want

Comment: @jmcilhinney this is the code
I want to show dialog can select a txt or tsv file or can input the path what i want to select
but OpenFileDialog only can select, inputting the path isn't possible 

the purpose is show the window to user, and user can select a file( directly select or input a path)

OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    If BatchMain(False, OpenFileDialog1.FileName, Me.CmbPROC_CLS.SelectedCode) Then
    End If
END If

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question and putting unformatted code in a comment at all is a no-no. Update your question and add all the relevant information that should have been there in the first place, then add a comment saying you've done that so that those who've already commented can be notified.

Comment: Have a look at [System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-7.0)

Comment: If I use OpenFileDialog in a form, I can absolutely just enter a path (and either hit Enter or click Open) and the dialog box will change to that folder.  I can also enter a full path name to the filename that I want to open.  Or I can use the dialog's own controls to navigate between folders.  You need to expand on exactly what it is that you want to do, that you feel you are unable to do ....

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense as it is. You are using two different `OpenFileDialog` instances and displaying them both. You display one and ignore the result, then display the second one. What's up with that?

Comment: You still haven't explained the problem properly. I still don't know whether you're talking about doing something in code or the user doing something in the UI. Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want the user to be able to paste an entire file path into the *File name* field of the dialogue? It really doesn't surprise me that so many people can't solve their problems when they clearly don't understand the problem in the first place based on how terrible their descriptions of the problems are. If you understand a problem, you can explain it FULLY and CLEARLY.

Comment: For the record, I just opened an `OpenFileDialog` and pasted the path of a file in that was in a folder other than the one that was currently open and that path was returned by the `FileName` property when the dialogue closed. It seems that that is one thing that you don't actually mean so again I say you need to explain what you're actually talking about. This should be very simple but it's a waste of our time to have to keep guessing and it means that you have to wait to get help that you should already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileName`  to set `Path` and `Filter` to set `File Type`

Ex:

```
        Dim oRes As Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        Dim strFileName As String
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .Title = "Please select a file."
            .FileName = "E:\2023\WindowsApp1\WindowsApp1\bin\Debug"
            .Filter = "File (*.txt,*.tsv)|*.txt;*.tsv"
            oRes = .ShowDialog
        End With
        If oRes <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Return
        End If
        strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```